# How to set the app always login until user click the logout button on ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I created a new mobile app in ionic3

If an user closes the app without clicking the logout button, the user should be logged in if he or she re-opens the app. However, if an user closes the app and re-opens it, login page appears.

How do I set up the app so the users stay logged in until they click the logout button?

Comment: Have any idea?? @Utpaul

Comment: I solve it please check.....

Comment: i already solve that...

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Ok,I will Check

Comment: you not update its work or not??

Comment: ya it works for me,thanks

Comment: Welcome @vignesh...... tnx for accepting..

Comment: i checked today only,sorry for accepting late

Comment: ok no problem ... also support for voting it.........

Comment: ok and thanks always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can recover it by using `localstorage`**

I will provide an example for you.As usal `app.component.ts` is load first so i need to work on it for which page are showing.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {ProfilePage} from "../pages/profile/profile";
import {LoginPage} from "../pages/login/login";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.initializeApp(statusBar, splashScreen);
    });

  }

  initializeApp(statusBar: StatusBar,
                splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    let username = window.localStorage.getItem('username') ? window.localStorage.getItem('username') : '';
    let password = window.localStorage.getItem('password') ? window.localStorage.getItem('password') : '';

    if(username == 'user' && password == 'user') {
      this.nav.setRoot(ProfilePage);
    }else{
      this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
    }
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();
  }
}
```

Here `username` and `pasword` are taken from localstorage if they have no value then its load `LoginPage`.In `LoginPage` you need to setup for storing `username` and `password` in localstorage.

```
  signIn(){

    if (this.loginForm.value.username=="user" && this.loginForm.value.password=="user") {
          window.localStorage.setItem('username', this.loginForm.value.username);
        window.localStorage.setItem('password', this.loginForm.value.password);
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(ProfilePage);
    }
  }
```

And also when you logout then destroy `username` and `password` localstorage value.

```
 window.localForage.removeItem('username')
 window.localForage.removeItem('password')
```

Comment: where to add this `window.localStorage.removeItem('username'),
 window.localStorage.removeItem('password')`.whether in `loginPage`

Comment: @vignesh give me feedback?

Comment: How about the security?

Comment: @ritesh update your questions what type of security you need ?

Comment: @Utpaul The security is all about: IS IT OK or SECUTE TO STORE TOKEN (access & refresh token) in LOCAL STORAGE in MOBILE APP? That is basically question as anybody (hacker) can easily read storage value so m abut reluctant to use it.

Comment: @RiteshAryal i will suggest you to see user question and answer. If you study in mobile technology then i think you will clear. If you have better solution then post your answer. I think it will be better

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I think they do that, is tracking the ip.  If the user enters from the same ip, and user has not log out (you have to save that info in a tb) the the script logs him/her in with user info ( that user info also in the former tb along with the ip)

YOu should have guessed that

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use JWT (https://jwt.io/) for authentication.

So, when users login, the jwt info would be stored in localStorage as well.
Of course, when user logout, JWT info in localStorage will be deleted.

When application is launched, I check localStorage and if there is a valid JWT info (JWT has valid time info as well), I use the JWT info.

I hope it would be helpful :)

Comment: what about when the token expires, the token will get deleted anyways...

Comment: @TejashriPatange Token is not deleted automatically. Token info still in localstorage as well. But when you check it is valid, it returns false. The logics to save or delete jwt into the localstorage should be implemented by developers in the login/logout function manually. :)

Comment: How about the security?